# Builed node.js in centos failed

Tags: centos, node.js

I'm trying to install node.js in my CentOS server,befor I run the  "make"commend,everything seems perfect.When I run the  `make` command and it produces the following:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out'
  g++ -o /usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out/Release/obj.host/v8_libbase/deps/v8/src/base/bits.o ../deps/v8/src/base/bits.cc '-DV8_GYP_BUILD' '-DV8_TYPED_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE_IN_HEAP=0' '-DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64' '-DV8_EMBEDDER_STRING="-node.51"' '-DENABLE_DISASSEMBLER' '-DV8_PROMISE_INTERNAL_FIELD_COUNT=1' '-DV8_INTL_SUPPORT' '-DV8_CONCURRENT_MARKING' '-DDISABLE_UNTRUSTED_CODE_MITIGATIONS' -I../deps/v8  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -O3 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=gnu++1y -MMD -MF /usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out/Release/.deps//usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out/Release/obj.host/v8_libbase/deps/v8/src/base/bits.o.d.raw   -c
make[1]: g++: Command not found
make[1]: *** [/usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out/Release/obj.host/v8_libbase/deps/v8/src/base/bits.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/node-v10.15.3/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Oh, when i run the `./configure`commend it produces the following:

```
WARNING: failed to autodetect C++ compiler version (CXX=g++)
creating icu_config.gypi
* Using ICU in deps/icu-small
WARNING: Using floating patch "tools/icu/patches/62/source/i18n/decimfmt.cpp" from "tools/icu"
```

I try to solve it by Google,but I'm not find anything help me.

Comment: Don't build this yourself. Use the [nodesource packages](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#rpm).

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `g++` by `sudo yum install gcc-c++`, in case any other build tool is needed, just `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` to install essential build tools